# Android Studio 3.0 - Cannot load any Android projects

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I updated to the latest Android Studio 3.0 version, and no matter what I do I cannot get a project to be properly recognized by Android Studio.

For one, Android Studio projects typically have the Android Studio icon instead of the typical folder icon in the file system, when browsing for a new project to open.

For two, this is what my project structure looks like - no modules, and I also cannot select "android" view instead of "project".

[image]

For three, I cannot run, build, or clean the project at all.

Sometimes when I open a project I get this error:

[image]

And sometimes that error doesn't show up at all.

Has anyone encountered this? I'm tried uninstalling Android Studio and re-installing it, installing the new 3.1 Canary 3 version, the stable version, nothing works. I've deleted and recloned every repository - I've tried many, big and small, and none work. I can compile fine from the command line though.

Many of these repos are used by other people currently using Android 3.0 stable and 3.0 Canary 3, and I'm the only one having issues, so I'm very certain it's not a repository issue. And if it is, I probably am not allowed to make whatever changes would be needed to fix this issue.

Comment: What are you exactly doing? You are importing or opening your project.
Try opening path of your project. I got my projects perfect by that.
File> Open

Comment: I'm opening the project. I select the root of the project as the file to open.

Comment: Okay i think your iml configuration file is damaged or something.

Delete your .iml file and try reopening your project

Comment: If that does not work 

Keep only these folders in your project folder and delete else.

folders - app, gradle, libraries if any.
files - build.gradle, setting.gradle, gradle.properties

and open your open your project.